# Array sort fails - objects without property gets put on top

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object array looking like this:

```
let plans = [
{
    surf: 5,
    price: 299,
    cprice: 199,
    cdur: 3,
},
{
    surf: 5,
    price: 249,
    cprice: 199,
    cdur: 3,
},
{
    surf: 15,
    price: 149,
    cprice: "",
    cdur: "",
},
];
```

And to sort the array I'm using a comparison looking like this:

```
    function cpriceDesc( a, b ) {
    if ( a.cprice < b.cprice ){
    return -1;
    }
    if ( a.cprice > b.cprice ){
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }

    function cpriceAsc( a, b ) {
    if ( a.cprice > b.cprice ){
    return -1;
    }
    if ( a.cprice < b.cprice ){
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

The sorting when a cprice is defined works properly but the object without a cprice value is always first in the array after sort. How can I put them last?

Comment: Why has your price property sometimes a data type of number and sometimes of string?

Comment: The cprice is a "campaign price" for a given duration (cdur property defines that). But not all have a campaign price, thus I want to (when sorting on cprice) show the cheapest to most expensive cprice first, and after that display the ones not having a price at all.

Comment: This does not answer the question why you mix data types.

Comment: Setting NaN messes up the sorting, setting a blank space does not work at all. What would you have suggested instead? Is your question relevant to my question?

Comment: I would suggest not using a string for this. Maybe consider not defining the property at all, so it just is absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number.isFinite` to distinguish normal numbers from anything else, like a string.

Note that your current sort-callback functions could be simplified to just a subtraction, like `return a.cprice - b.cprice`. To add the above discrimination to it, you can subtract like this `Number.isFinite(b.cprice) - Number.isFinite(a.cprice)` and when that is 0 (they are both of the same "category") continue with the `a.cprice - b.cprice` subtraction (or its inverse):

```js
const plans = [{surf: 5,price: 299,cprice: 199,cdur: 3,},{surf: 5,price: 249,cprice: 199,cdur: 3,},{surf: 15,price: 149,cprice: "",cdur: "",},];

const sortAsc = (a, b) => Number.isFinite(b.cprice) - Number.isFinite(a.cprice) || a.cprice - b.cprice;
const sortDesc = (a, b) => Number.isFinite(b.cprice) - Number.isFinite(a.cprice) || b.cprice - a.cprice;

console.log(plans.sort(sortDesc));
```

I would not advise to define your prices as strings when there is no price. Instead just don't have that property at all. If you would do that, the above code will still work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the empty string and move this values to bottom, otherwise sort by the value.

```js
let
    plans = [{ surf: 5, price: 14, cprice: "", cdur: "" }, { surf: 5, price: 299, cprice: 198, cdur: 3 }, { surf: 5, price: 249, cprice: 199, cdur: 3 }, { surf: 15, price: 149, cprice: "", cdur: "" }];
    

plans.sort((a, b) =>
    (a.cprice === '') - (b.cprice === '') ||
    a.cprice - b.cprice
);

console.log(plans)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```